# Pulling cable: Torsion relief

Tags: cable-management, cat6

I'm laying out 70 meters U/UTP cat 6 cables between two floors, and I was wondering if someone had a strategy to remove as much torsion as possible from a cable as it is pulled from its roll ?

is this something I should worry about for the long term quality of the cable ? (Fluke testing says that cable is fine)

Comment: Torsion or tension?

Answer (score 5):

We've not had any special strategy other than unspooling and pulling in segments along the way to relieve stress on the cable. Pull a little, move down, pull again, move down, repeat until reaching destination. Then pull a little more for slack.

Once pulled and tested there shouldn't be any other problems over time with the cabling if it's testing okay as long as no other load is placed on the cable; i.e., is it resting a lot of weight on a small hook or other support that concentrates the weight of the cables in one small spot, or if it's hanging a large amount of cable vertically so the weight is pulling down on the line. Offset this with proper support at short intervals.

If the plastic outer jacket turned white at some point in the pull...you may have a slight problem. We've seen older weird-acting cable removed from sites that was white cat-5. Thought it was strange until we reached another part of the line where the jacket was blue again. Guess that helped solve the mystery of flaky performance from those lines...